# LINQ Datatable and Select columns

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Sorry about my English.

1. I have a list with column names what i need to select.
2. I have a datatable(Nr1) with many columns(40) and rows(2000)
3. I need to get a new DataTable(Nr2) with data, where i have columns from;

   `datatable(Nr1).column.name = list items and also data from this column.`

I have;

```
token_datatable_ As Data.DataTable
```

and;

```
token_columnList As List(Of String)
```

and

```
Dim retTable As DataTable = New DataTable 'This is new table what i need to get

Dim query = From element In datatable_, element_ As String In token_columnList
                Select element.Field(Of Object)(element_) 'something like this i need?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need LINQ at all.

Just use a `DataView` and the `ToTable` method, like

```
Dim newTable = New DataView(originalTable).ToTable(False, columnList.ToArray())
```

This will create a new `DataTable` with only the columns of `originalTable` whose names are in `columnList` .